# systemd service not updating after linked file is modified

Tags: ubuntu, python, systemctl

My KBot.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description = 'Service for Discord bot'
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/python/venv /path/to/KBot.py   #(These are absolute paths)
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I update the KBot.py file. and then run:

`sudo systemctl restart KBot`

or

`sudo systemctl stop KBot`

`sudo systemctl start KBot`

or

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo systemctl restart KBot`

or any variation of the above, systemctl refuses to use the new updated file and keeps the running the old code. How do i get systemctl to clear its cache. I have even tried rebooting my pc multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in my code. I mistyped the name of a method in a function.

confirmed it was a bug by checking `sudo journalctl -u KBot | tail`